# How to store image into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL database along with PHP. How to implement a process to store an image in my database.

Comment: don't. store file, in the file system

Comment: how? how are you getting the files?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can store image in folder and name in database table with varchar data type

   Ex: if image, then filestoredpath/abc.png will be stored in table and abc.png will stored in folder
2. image longblob data type in database table
   then take img as `$img = file_get_contents($image);`
   then insert into table with query "insert into images (image) values (?)";

Comment: storing images or any file in the DB is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: yes i agree with you but as he had asked so i provide a way to accomplish it .but i always prefer to path stored in DB and file in folder

Comment: ok understood should I store in a folder? if yes how to relate it to the database?@rtfm

Comment: @GnetoDominiquePageHome store the filename\path in the db

Comment: you can store image using `move_uploaded file` function of php in desired path and create one variable with data for ex: "storedpath".$imgname,image name should be with extension ,  and now stored this variable in DB,so whenever you want to display that image,just echo that variable from DB into <img src="" ?> tag

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files'['tmp_name'],"upload/".$_FILES['files']['name']);$img="upload/".$_FILES['files']['name'];
$query="Insert into image values (0,'".$img."')";
mysql_query($query);.......Now to display image :<img src="<?php echo "base url will come ex: http://localhost/foldername"."/upload/2.jpg";?>"> ""/upload/2.jpg"" is a image name stored in DB

Comment: @SoniaGupta Thanks miss I think I will try this and give you the result in a couple of minute

Answer (score -1):

For **storing image** to **database**, you can do like this :

1. First upload the image in to you server.You can done this with this code

   ```
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
    $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
    $newname = "newname.".rand(0,999).$ext;
    $target = 'images/'.$newname;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target)
   ```
2. Now store the image path that is in `$target`  variable to you DB then you can get the image through the image path.